# Submit login with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I press the Login button I get a 500 Internal server error in the console. What's the right way to get POST using jQuery? Can you help me?

```html
<button class="login100-form-btn" type="submit" name="login" value="login" id="Login">
  Login
</button>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#Login").click(function() {
    var username_val = $("#username").val();
    var password_val = $("#password").val();
    var info_creds = 'username=' + username_val + '&password=' + password_val;

    if (username_val == '' || password_val == '') {
      $("#alert_response_ko").show();
      $("#alert_response_ko").html("<p>Devi inserire username e password!</p>");
      $("#alert_response_ko").fadeOut(8000);
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: info_creds,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
          if (response == 'wrong!') {
            console.log('ko');
            $("#alert_response_ko").show();
            $("#alert_response_ko").html("<p>Username e/o Password Errati!</p>");
            $("#alert_response_ko").fadeOut(8000);
          }

          if (response == 'login_ok!') {
            console.log('ok');
            window.setTimeout(function() {
              window.location.href = './homepage.php';
            }, 10);
          }
        }
      });
    }
    
    return false;
  })
});
```

Comment: Some error ocurrs in server side. Share your  code server side.

Comment: A 500 error means that the error itself is on the server side, not your JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 500 Internal Server Error is a "server-side" error, meaning the problem is not with your PC or Internet connection but instead is a problem with the web site's server.

> If you want to use Post, you have to send data as Object Change your
> Ajax Function to...

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'login.php',
            data: {
                username: username_val,
                password: password_val,
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == 'wrong!') {
                    console.log('ko');
                    $('#alert_response_ko').show();
                    $('#alert_response_ko').html(
                        '<p>Username e/o Password Errati!</p>'
                    );
                    $('#alert_response_ko').fadeOut(8000);
                }

                if (response == 'login_ok!') {
                    console.log('ok');
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        window.location.href = './homepage.php';
                    }, 10);
                }
            },
        });
```

Comment: Thank you! this solved my issue. By the way, 500 internal error was due to a typo in "login.php". There was an "goto something:" instead of "goto something;"

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  function showAlert(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    $("#alert_response_ko").html("<p>" + msg + "</p>").show().fadeOut(8000);
  }

  function login(page, user, pass) {
    $.ajax({
      url: page,
      data: {
        username: user,
        password: pass
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(results) {
        if (results == 'login_ok!') {
          console.log('Login Successful');
          window.setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = './homepage.php';
          }, 10);
        } else {
          showAlert("Username e/o Password Errati!");
        }
      },
      error: function(x, e, n) {
        showAlert("Username e/o Password Errati! " + e + ", " + n);
      }
    });
  }

  $("#Login").closest("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var username_val = $("#username").val();
    var password_val = $("#password").val();

    if (username_val == '' || password_val == '') {
      showAlert("Devi inserire username e password!");
    } else {
      login("login.php", username_val, password_val);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="User" /> <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" /> <button class="login100-form-btn" type="submit" name="login" value="login" id="Login">
  Login
</button>
</form>
<div id="alert_response_ko"></div>
```

This might help identify issues. As was suggested, the `500` status is a general Web Server failure. It means that the Web Server encountered an error and may be configured to suppress the error message itself.

Check your PHP Logs and Error handling settings. Better to reveal errors while testing and then hide them when in production.